# Accordion in a column of ASP.net GridView

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview, accordion

I have a requirement like, I need to put Accordion inside a Gridview column and whenever a user clicks on the accordion's header it should open and close.

I have searched over the Google for solution but I couldn't find the actual solution instead everyone have explained about JQuery Accordion in repeater only.

I have tried the [solution in this link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Populate-jQuery-Accordion-with-data-from-Database-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx) but no use.

Can any body help me out in this?

```
<asp:GridView>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Accordion"
     HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true"
     HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Black">
     <ItemTemplate>
         **This is where I need to display Accordion**           
     </ItemTemplate>

</asp:TemplateField>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: post your html here?

Comment: Hi @FrebinFrancis I had put the html code now....

Comment: you have any other columns in your grid?

Comment: Yeah, I have few more columns and this is the last column. I am binding data from database to other columns in this gridview.

Comment: i posted my answer please take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for posting answer for my question.
I have solved my problem and achieved it. Here I am posting my answer and if you find anything improper here plz leave a comment for the same.

- First I added an **OnRowDataBound** event to my GridView.
- Then I have placed an **asp:Panel** control inside the **asp:TemplateField** in my GridView as follows:

  ```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Accordion"
  HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true"
  HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Black">
     <ItemTemplate>
        <div id="accordion2" class="panel-group">
           <asp:Panel ID="pnl" runat="server">
           </asp:Panel>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
  ```
- Then in code behind I have written the following code to add Accordion to this Panel.

  ```
  protected void LoadAccordion(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {
      DataRowView drv = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

      if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
      {
          Panel p = (Panel)e.Row.FindControl("pnl");
          p.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='panel'><div class='panel-heading'><a href='#collapse" + e.Row.RowIndex + "' data-parent='#accordion2' data-toggle='collapse' class='accordion-toggle collapsed'>Statistics</a></div><div style='height: 0px;' class='panel-collapse collapse' id='collapse" + e.Row.RowIndex + "'><div class='panel-body'>Sample Text Here...</div></div></div>"));
      }

  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 511px; border: none; overflow: auto;">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView2"
            runat="server"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            GridLines="None"
            AllowSorting="True"
            CssClass="tbl_body"
            CellPadding="0"
            CellSpacing="0"
            ShowHeader="false"
            Width="100%">
            <Columns>
                <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="runId" DataTextField="runId" HeaderText="RunID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="RunAnalysis.aspx?runId={0}">
                    <ItemStyle Width="20%" />
                </asp:HyperLinkField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="prodDate" HeaderText="Date" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yy}">
                    <ItemStyle Width="20%" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="buildNumber" HeaderText="Build Number">
                    <ItemStyle Width="20%" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="PercentAnalysed" DataTextField="PercentAnalysed" HeaderText="Percent Analysed">
                    <ItemStyle Width="20%" />
                </asp:HyperLinkField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Accordion"
                    HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true"
                    HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Black">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="accordion">
                            <h3>Section 1</h3>
                            <div>
                                <p>
                                    Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <h3>Section 2</h3>
                            <div>
                                <p>
                                    Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet   
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <h3>Section 3</h3>
                            <div>
                                <p>
                                    Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.   
                                </p>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>List item one</li>
                                    <li>List item two</li>
                                    <li>List item three</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <h3>Section 4</h3>
                            <div>
                                <p>
                                    Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus  mauris vel est.
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(".accordion").accordion();
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

[image: Check the image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Accordion panel, you can achieve the same functionality by adding a hidden  in GridView ItemTemplate and Expand/Collapse images. The GridView Html looks like,

```
<Columns>
   <asp:TemplateField>
       <ItemTemplate>
           <a href="javascript:switchViews('div<%# Eval("Id") %>', 'one');">
              <img id="imgdiv<%# Eval("Id") %>" alt="Click to show/hide" border="0" src="../Images/expand_button.png" />
              </a>
       </ItemTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>
         </td></tr>
          <tr>
             <td colspan="100%">
                 <div id="div<%# Eval("Id") %>" style="display: none; position: relative; left: 25px;">
                    <!-- Your Content Here -->
                  </div>
               </td>
              </tr>
         </ItemTemplate>
```

and your javascript code is,

```
function switchViews(obj, row) {
            var div = document.getElementById(obj);
            var img = document.getElementById('img' + obj);

            if (div.style.display == "none") {
                div.style.display = "inline";
                if (row == 'alt') {
                    img.src = "../Images/expand_button_down.png"; 
                }
                else {
                    img.src = "../Images/expand_button_down.png";
                }
            }
            else {
                div.style.display = "none";
                if (row == 'alt') {
                    img.src = "../Images/expand_button.png"; 
                }
                else {
                    img.src = "../Images/expand_button.png";
                }
                img.alt = "Expand to show orders";
            }
        }
```